# Rails AASM automatic state transition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, aasm

I am working on a Rails app that is using the `AASM` gem to transition a particular object to different states.

There is a need to have an initial state of "pre-approval" but only if the attribute of "accepted" is set to false. Is there a way to do automatic transitions using the `AASM` gem?

Here are the states:

```
  aasm column: :status do
    state :pre_approval, initial: true
    state :pending
    state :opened
    state :closed

    event :approved do
      transitions from: :pre_approval, to: :pending, guard: :approved_changed?
    end

    event :received, after: Proc.new { set_received_date } do
      transitions from: :pending, to: :opened
    end

    event :complete, after: Proc.new { set_completion_date } do
      transitions from: :opened, to: :closed
    end
  end
```

Comment: So, you mean whenever the `accepted` attribute is changed to `true`, you want the `status` column to be automatically set to `pending` by `AASM` (sort of in the background)?

Answer (score 0):

Here you can see a list of all possible callbacks, together with their order of calling:

```
begin
  event           before
  event           guards
  transition      guards
  old_state       before_exit
  old_state       exit
  transition      after
  new_state       before_enter
  new_state       enter
  ...update state...
  event         success             # if persist successful
  old_state       after_exit
  new_state       after_enter
  event           after
rescue
  event           error
end
```

There are three callbacks for the new state: before_enter,enter,after_enter,but no guards.So I think if you want set initial state when some conditions be true,the best way is using rails's `before_create` callback.

BTW, I don't think aasm should add guards for the state.Because the state is specific status,not a action.We just can add callback enter or exit this status.

> Is there a way to do automatic transitions using the AASM gem?

No,but you can invoke a event in the aasm callbacks or rails callbacks.